# How to add IFrame tool in CKEditor?

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I am customizing the CKEditor tool bar. I want to add IFrame, how to do this?

My code I have tried:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1',{
            toolbar :
                [
                    ['SpellChecker','Bold', 'Italic','Underline','Subscript','Superscript'],
                    ['NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Blockquote','-','JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],
                    ['Link', 'Unlink','Anchor'] ,['Image','Flash','Table','HorizontalRule','SpecialChar','IFrame'],
                    '/',
                    ['Styles','Format','Font','FontSize' ],
                    ['TextColor','BGColor'],
                    ['Maximize']
                ]
            });
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am using ckeditor in a project of my own, my config file looks like this. I reference the IFrame plugin with a lowercase 'f'.

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {

config.toolbar = 'Full';
config.toolbar_Full =
[
    { name: 'document', items: ['Source', '-', 'Save', 'NewPage', 'Preview', 'Print', '-', 'Templates'] },
    { name: 'clipboard', items: ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo'] },
    { name: 'editing', items: ['Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', '-', 'SpellChecker', 'Scayt'] },
    { name: 'forms', items: ['Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton',
        'HiddenField']
    },
    '/',
    { name: 'basicstyles', items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat'] },
    { name: 'paragraph', items: ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv',
    '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl']
    },
    { name: 'links', items: ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor'] },
    { name: 'insert', items: ['Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak', 'Iframe'] },
    '/',
    { name: 'styles', items: ['Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize'] },
    { name: 'colors', items: ['TextColor', 'BGColor'] },
    { name: 'tools', items: ['Maximize', 'ShowBlocks', '-', 'About'] }
];
};
```